# Loading Activity on App Start via Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a app working with share preferences (first time), however, my first activity to run is the one that checks for the set preferences. So when the app loads you get this "black screen" then the correct activity loads.

My application is extending a Navigation Activity and I did attempt to run it out of this activity, however, I do not have an onStart, onCreate() etc... in there since it is just inflating the Actionbar Sherlock menu. If I add onStart() I get an error. I get an infinite loop if I add:

```
onStart(){getPrefs();super.onStart();}
```

So, can anyone share with me how / where I should run this so that the user does not get the "black screen" then the correct activity? I want just the correct activity to start when the app starts.

Here is how I currently load my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {
    private AQuery aq;
    SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    private String lp;
    private String TAG = "GET PREFS";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // show no back arrow
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstload);

        aq = new AQuery(this);

        getPrefs();

        aq.id(R.id.tv).text("Loading...");

    }

    private void getPrefs() {
        // Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        lp = prefs.getString("defaultreport", "");
        Log.v(TAG, lp);

        if (lp.equals("esac")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ESAC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ESACActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (lp.equals("sac")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SAC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SACActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (lp.equals("msar")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MSAR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MSARActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

}
```

My NavigationActivity contains:

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

and 

onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

EDIT::

I have thought about adding a Splash screen on start-up to accommodate this settings change, but would love to see another streamlined solution.

EDIT EDIT::

I tried @MrZander suggestion, but am running into an issue in my Manifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/acricon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" 
        android:name="com.Conditions.MainActivity" //This loads the PREFS fine
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.Conditions.SACActivity" //However, defining this negates the PREFS. My apps first screen is defined by the PREFS. 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would override the app's `Application`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Something along the lines of this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //Shared prefs here
    }
}
```

And in your manifest's `<application>` tag add this property: `android:name="com.your.package.MyApplication"`

Comment: Ok, so I tried this. My Main Activity that loads is determined by the preferences. When I do this, the Manifest still requires a .MAIN intent, which needs to be an Activity from what I gather. I updated my question with the Manifest...

Comment: I see. A splash screen may be your only option in this case.

Comment: After the first load of the app, the transition from the MainActivity to the PREF'd activity is fairly seemless... it's just got that tiny transition time I'd like to hide. No biggie there though really. Thanks for the comment though. Learned something new and valuable with the extends Application idea!